# How to upload files on FTP in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to upload files in FTP server. How to implement this functionality.

I have tried many libraries like raccoons, [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) but these libraries have deprecated code which does not work.

```
NSURL *url_upload = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://username:password!@host:port/filename.wav"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url_upload];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
        NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"1kb" ofType:@"png"];
        NSURL *docsDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    NSURLProtectionSpace * protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:url_upload.host port:[url_upload.port integerValue] protocol:url_upload.scheme realm:nil authenticationMethod:nil];

    NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential
                             credentialWithUser:@"username"
                             password:@"pass!"
                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


    NSURLCredentialStorage * cred_storage ;
    [cred_storage setCredential:cred forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfig.URLCredentialStorage = cred_storage;


    NSURLSession *upLoadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [upLoadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:docsDirURL completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error != NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else{

        }
    }];

    [uploadTask resume];
```

Please suggest me some swift or objective c implementation to upload the file on FTP server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

https://github.com/amosavian/FileProvider

```
let returnCredential = URLCredential(user:<username>, password:<password>, persistence: .none)

let ftpFileProvider = FTPFileProvider(baseURL: URL(string:<host eg ftp:>, mode: .default, credential: returnCredential, cache: .none)!
ftpFileProvider.copyItem(localFile: <local_file_path>, to:<where on ftp>, completionHandler: { error in         
   if error != nil {
      print(error)
      return
   }
})
```

Comment: FTPS should work. Not testet. SFTP will not. But it was not the question.

Comment: @PintuRajput Why not?

Comment: Not accepting the URL likeL ftp://0.5.20.10/newfolder/sample.png

Comment: This repo is disabled.